# java boolean method return always false

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, boolean

I wrote this method to check if the code valid or not:

```
private boolean validateDeleteBacklog(String code) {
        if(code != null && !code.equals("")) {
            if(code.length() == 6) {
                Pattern specialCaracter = Pattern.compile("[$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.-^*()%!]");
                boolean specialCar = specialCaracter.matcher(code).matches();
                return specialCar; 
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

when i use code = "abc123" it return always false inside of true.
Where is the problem here?

Comment: `if(code != null && !code.equals(""))` use `equals()` to compare String values

Comment: @Hülya i did and when i try code="abc" it returns false inside of true

Comment: debug your code to see what's going on...

Comment: This is actually a completely different question. The problem now is that the whole string must match the pattern, but the pattern matches just one character.

Comment: @Henry Can you explain more please?